# How to make Alt+X stop closing current document in Notepad++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

In Notepad++, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> always closes current document, even if the keyboard shortcut is not assigned anywhere in the Shortcut Mapper. What is the source of this behavior and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source is the barely noticeable `X` item on the right side of the main menu bar.

The easiest way to stop <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> activating that item is to assign this keyboard shortcut to another command in the **Shortcut Mapper**. For example, assign it to **File** > **Rename...** because it always displays a window (asking for new file name) before executing the command so unwanted activation can be canceled by <kbd>Esc</kbd> before it does anything.

Alternative solutions proposed by other people: https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/3b917b41/